# qt- how to move a picture in a slow motion

Tags: qt

I am trying to move a picture slowly from one position to another in QGraphicsScene. So I tried to use sleep, after that much of milli seconds I tried "setPos". But is not doing as I thought. Some body please help me

Comment: What is it doing and why is that different from what you expected?

Comment: it just freezing for some seconds, then it immediately position it in some other place.

Answer (score 3):

sleep() is never what you want in an UI thread, as it blocks everything.
Have a look at QGraphicsItemAnimation (setPosAt()) and QTimeLine.